# Is MaxClientsVhost the definite visitor limit?

Tags: apache2, apache2-module

Having a hard time figuring the exact "math" around the `apache2-mpm-itk` configuration option `MaxClientsVhost`

We are running one front-end server with nginx, and are proxying traffic to our two back-end servers running `Apache` with `apache2-mpm-itk`.

Each `Vhost` is now running as its own instance so they won't affect each other. However, if a `Vhost` has a set limit of `MaxClientsVhost 250`, does this mean that we in theory have a max capacity of 500 visitors at any one time?

If so, how long does a visitor remain a visitor, until that one spot is once again freed for the next?

I also remember tinkering with the maximum connection properties for apache before, and I seem to remember that the values set her, we're affected by each other with something like how many connection per apache sub-worker or something. Is this also the case for `apache2-mpm-itk`?

**Does these values affect the MaxClientsVhost in any way?**

```
StartServers        8
MinSpareServers     5
MaxSpareServers     20
ServerLimit         256
MaxClients          256
MaxRequestsPerChild 4000
```